# How to add a Date type in a swift JSON body

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Hello I’m very new to swift and I want to `POST` data to a server but I only found how to make a `body` with `Strings` and I want to be able to have a `Date` key and value. Would love any suggestions anyone has :)

Code:

```
let body: [String: String] = ["device": device, "version": version, "model": model, "problem": userInput]
```

Comment: simply change your dictionary declaration to `let body: [String: Any]` and add the `Date` as value to dictionary, `let body: [String: Any] = ["device": device, "version": version, "model": model, "problem": userInput, "date": Date()]` that should do. Obviously I hardcoded `Date()` you can pass your custom Date instance instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass date as string. Firstly convert Date() to string and then just add it.

let date = Date()

```
let body: [String: String] = ["device": device, "version": version, "model": model, "problem": userInput, "date": "\(date)"]
```

Here, date is a time string.